# How to write a query for autocomplete in mysqli?

Tags: php, mysqli, autocomplete

code:

```
<?php
  include('config.php');
  $return_arr = array();
  $term = $_GET['term'];
  $term = str_replace('.','',$term);
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM submission where keyword like '".$term."%' or keyword 
  like '%".$term."%' ORDER BY CASE WHEN keyword LIKE '".$term."%' THEN 1
  ELSE 2 END";
  $r = mysqli_query($link,$sql);
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r))
  {
    $key = explode(",", $row['keyword']);
    foreach ($key as $keyword) 
    {
      $return_arr[] = $keyword;
    }  
  }
  echo json_encode($return_arr);
?>
```

I have created autocomplete suggestion box and its working properly but I have a column name keyword where my data is look line apolo,alto,bmw,camaro,ducati like this where I am using expload function for listing one by one. If I search with (a) alphabet it showing a result but when I want to search with (b) alphabet its show nothing. So, How can I remove this problem ?Please help me.

Thank You

Comment: I am trying this @Cashbee but it showing same result.

Answer (score 0):

Use the IN filter to get better results for multiple keywords

```
SELECT keyword FROM submission WHERE keyword IN ('Apolo', 'BMW', ...);
```

Comment: it display unknown column 'a' in where clause @rak007

Comment: @omkara please be more precise, I don't understand

Comment: I am using IN clause in phpmyadmin and run your query as you mention but it show nothing buddy. I have run like SELECT keyword FROM submission WHERE keyword IN (Apolo); so it showing unknown column 'Apolo' in where clause.

Comment: Select * then, I can't guess how your database is sorry